# Как изменить ContentControl изнутри, в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Только пытаюсь разобраться с Wpf MVMM.Есть такая разметка.

```cs
<Window x:Class="RealPolyclinic.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="AdPViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:AddPatientVM}">
            <views:AddPatient />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SrchViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:SearchPatientVM}">
            <views:SearchPatient/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="OneMorePViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:OneMoreVM}">
            <views:OneMoreView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="Black">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Command="{Binding gotoAdp}">1st page</Button>
                <Button Command="{Binding gotoSrch}">2nd PAge</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="5" Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Ей принадлежит такая ViewModel:MainVM.

```
public class MainVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        private BaseViewModel _currentView;
        public BaseViewModel CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand gotoAdp { get; set; }
        public ICommand gotoSrch { get; set; }

        public MainVM()
        {
            gotoAdp = new RelayCommand(x => CurrentView = new AddPatientVM());
            gotoSrch = new RelayCommand(x => CurrentView = new SearchPatientVM());
        }
    }
```

При переходе на любой из пользовательских UserControl.К примеру.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RealPolyclinic.Views.AddPatient"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic.ViewModels"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:RealPolyclinic.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding NextView}">Privet</Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

И его ViewModel.

```
public class AddPatientVM : MainVM
    {
        public ICommand NextView { get; set; }
        public AddPatientVM()
        {
            NextView = new RelayCommand(x => CurrentView = new OneMoreVM());
        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь изменить свойство CurrentView как и в MainVm, но никакого эффекта,думаю это связано с DataContext.
При нажатии кнопки в UserControl хотелось бы осуществить переход на любой другой UserControl.Соответственно нужно каким-то образом изменить свойство Content(ContentControl) в основном Window,каким образом это можно осуществить,используя MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Просто теория:

Объявите поле в вашей `VM` к примеру следующего типа:

```
public enum ViewType
{
    AddPatient,
    SearchPatient,
    OneMoreView
}
```

Далее делаете привязку к примеру на `Tag` вашего `ContentControl`, и меняете именно его.

А далее просто пишите триггер стилей для `ContentControl` где в зависимости от установленного тега, устанавливалась бы, необходимая `View`.

---

Оффтопик:

Вообще рекомендую изучить [Prism Library](http://prismlibrary.github.io/), и взаимодействовать с регионами. Как пример, вы могли бы спокойно взять и определить в регионе активное `View`, а то что не нужно, сделать неактивным, таким образом ваш контент бы менялся в зависимости от потребностей.

Comment: Понял, а не могли бы подсказать как можно изменить DataContext переходя в UserControl,на его ViewModel.

Comment: Не надо менять `DataContext`! Меняйте контент через триггер! Но не `DataContext`.